# Python strip Google Alerts URL

Tags: python, regex, urllib2

I've currently got a dataframe filled with Google Alert URLS that look like:

```
link = 'https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=http://3dprint.com/4353/littledlper-dlp-3d-printer-kickstarter/&ct=ga&cd=CAEYBCoSODQ1OTg1ODMwMzQwNDUzMTUxMhw2NTFlMTg3MTI1ZGE4Nzc3OmNvLnVrOmVuOkdC&usg=AFQjCNF0HOEhqIZHEpdkH1eVdXt-JRBF3Q'
```

and I just want the part following `url=` and before the junk.

```
http://3dprint.com/4353/littledlper-dlp-3d-printer-kickstarter/
```

I used `urllib.parse.urlparse(link)` to get a list of URL elements...

```
parsed = ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='www.google.com', path='/url', params='', query='rct=j&sa=t&url=http://3dprint.com/4353/littledlper-dlp-3d-printer-kickstarter/&ct=ga&cd=CAEYBCoSODQ1OTg1ODMwMzQwNDUzMTUxMhw2NTFlMTg3MTI1ZGE4Nzc3OmNvLnVrOmVuOkdC&usg=AFQjCNF0HOEhqIZHEpdkH1eVdXt-JRBF3Q', fragment='')
```

but even then `parsed[4]` only breaks it down to...

```
'rct=j&sa=t&url=http://3dprint.com/4353/littledlper-dlp-3d-printer-kickstarter/&ct=ga&cd=CAEYBCoSODQ1OTg1ODMwMzQwNDUzMTUxMhw2NTFlMTg3MTI1ZGE4Nzc3OmNvLnVrOmVuOkdC&usg=AFQjCNF0HOEhqIZHEpdkH1eVdXt-JRBF3Q'
```

I found [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39088532/i-need-to-strip-a-google-alerts-url) [queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777513/extract-original-url-from-google-alerts-link) on Stack with this same question but they were in other programming languages than Python.

Any ideas on a Python approach?

Comment: My one liner will be --- [x.split('=')[1] for x in line.split('&') if x.split('=')[0] == 'url'][0]  -- where line is input string

Comment: Thanks. Looks elegant and worked on the example I provided, but with variance in the URL structure over time ( I have about 13,000 URLS) I found the Regex easier to amend to capture the different varieties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex on `parsed[4]` to extract that URL:

```
(?:^|&)url=([^&]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sG7yY1/1)

*Details*:

- `(?:^|&)` - either start of string or `&`
- `url=` - literal text `url=`
- `([^&]+)` - Group 1 capturing one or more symbols other than `&`.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/BtRIlP):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?:^|&)url=([^&]+)')
s = "rct=j&sa=t&url=http://3dprint.com/4353/littledlper-dlp-3d-printer-kickstarter/&ct=ga&cd=CAEYBCoSODQ1OTg1ODMwMzQwNDUzMTUxMhw2NTFlMTg3MTI1ZGE4Nzc3OmNvLnVrOmVuOkdC&usg=AFQjCNF0HOEhqIZHEpdkH1eVdXt-JRBF3Q"
mObj = p.search(s)
if mObj:
    print(mObj.group(1))
```

Comment: Wow! That was quick, and very helpfully detailed! Regex is like voodoo to me but this really lays out how each group works. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, capturing is relatively easy. You could try using a positive lookahead like `r'(?<=\burl=)[^&]+'` (then, you'd have the value in `mObj.group()`), but I think capturing is a more appropriate and flexible mechanism to use here. You use the ID of the group to the `mObj.group()` method and get its contents.

Comment: Thanks again. I actually found some variance over time in the way the URLs were constructed but with your explanation above I was able to amend the regex to cover all eventualities.

For anyone that wants it `(?:^|&)(?:url|q)=([^&|%]+)`

Comment: I think you actually need to use `(?:^|&)(?:url|q)=([^&%]+)`. The `|` inside `[...]` is treated as  a literal pipe symbol, not an alternation operator

Comment: Ah, thanks, didn't realise. I guess it will still work, it will just have that redundant pipe in there too. Script is currently running so I'll see how it works out and correct after.